# Converting letters to numbers in entire dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I am having trouble applying the `chartr()` function on all columns of my data frame for converting letters to numbers.

I managed doing it on single columns, yet I want to be able to do it on the entire data frame. Here is an example of my data:

```
ID = c(1,2,3)
POS1 = c('AG','GC','TT')
POS2 = c('GT','CC','TC')
POS3 = c('GG','CT','AT')
DF = data.frame(ID,POS1,POS2,POS3)

DF$POS1X <- chartr('ACGT','1234',DF$POS1)

  ID POS1 POS2 POS3 POS1X
1  1   AG   GT   GG    13
2  2   GC   CC   CT    32
3  3   TT   TC   AT    44
```

As seen from the code, I want to convert A to 1, C to 2, G to 3, and T to 4. I have 40+ columns and thus repeating the same command as above 40+ times would be impractical (especially if I run into the same problem later on with say hundreds of columns)

Sincerily,
ykl

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Why not use `lapply`?

```
DF2 <- DF ## to not overwrite the original DF
DF2[-1] <- lapply(DF2[-1], chartr, old = "ACGT", new = "1234")
DF2
#   ID POS1 POS2 POS3
# 1  1   13   34   33
# 2  2   32   22   24
# 3  3   44   42   14
```

Now you have two data frames with equivalent column names which I find easier to compare than appending new columns to the old data.  Especially when there are many many columns.

Answer (score 4):

Using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
DF %>% mutate_each(funs(chartr("ACGT", "1234", .)))
```

You get:

```
  ID POS1 POS2 POS3
1  1   13   34   33
2  2   32   22   24
3  3   44   42   14
```

Answer (score 3):

```
> cbind(DF, setNames( lapply( DF[-1], chartr, old='ACGT', new='1234'), 
                      paste0("POS", 1:(length(DF)-1),"X"))  )
  ID POS1 POS2 POS3 POS1X POS2X POS3X
1  1   AG   GT   GG    13    34    33
2  2   GC   CC   CT    32    22    24
3  3   TT   TC   AT    44    42    14
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also use `mgsub` from `qdap`

```
library(qdap)
DF[paste0('POS', 1:3,'X')] <- mgsub(c('A', 'C', 'G', 'T'), 1:4, 
               as.matrix(DF[-1]))
DF
#  ID POS1 POS2 POS3 POS1X POS2X POS3X
#1  1   AG   GT   GG    13    34    33
#2  2   GC   CC   CT    32    22    24
#3  3   TT   TC   AT    44    42    14
```