# Running an ifelse() in lists

Tags: r, if-statement

I have this list here:

```
 structure(list(`1` = c("4", "*", ".", ".", "*", ".", ".", "*", 
"*", ".", "*", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "."), `2` = c("5", ".", 
".", ".", ".", ".", "*", ".", ".", ".", "*", ".", ".", ".", ".", 
"*", ".", "*", ".", ".", "*", "*", "*", "*", "*", "."), `3` = c("4", 
".", ".", ".", ".", "*", ".", ".", "*", ".", ".", "a", "*", ".", 
"*", ".", ".")), .Names = c("1", "2", "3"))
```

I would like to change the symbols (* and .) to numbers (* to a 0 and . to a 1) inside each list.

Incidentally, if any thing else than a symbol comes up (like a letter), than I would like the list to print NA.

I've tried this, which doesn't change anything...

```
ifelse(board_split_vec == "*", 0, 
      ifelse(board_split_vec == ".", 1, board_split_vec))
```

Ideally, I have to find a way to do this using Base R functions..no packages please!

Comment: Ooops! I dputted the wrong data. Let me fix this . 
UPDATE: just put in the right data! Thanks for pointing this out @42-

Comment: Would you want to keep the number "4", or does it become "NA"?

Comment: I want to keep all the numbers like 4 or 5. I just want the letters to be NA @zx8754

Comment: Based on [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27661170/2204410): `lapply(board_split_vec, function(i) as.numeric(chartr("*.", "01", i)) )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be fairly efficient. Assignment via logical indexing:

```
  ( board_split_vec <- lapply( board_split_vec, 
                   function(x){ x[ x=="*"] <- 0; x[x=="."] <- 1; as.numeric(x)}) ) 
$`1`
 [1] 4 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1

$`2`
 [1] 5 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1

$`3`
 [1]  4  1  1  1  1  0  1  1  0  1  1 NA  0  1  0  1  1
```

Answer (score 3):

You could also use `lapply` and `match` like this:

```
lapply(x, function(y) match(y, table=c(".","*", "2", "3", "4", "5")) - 1L)
```

This returns:

```
$`1`
 [1] 4 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0

$`2`
 [1] 5 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0

$`3`
 [1]  4  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  1  0  0 NA  1  0  1  0  0
```

We use the positions returned by `match` and then subtract 1 to get the desired 0, 1 returns. When an element is not in the table argument of `match`, it returns NA by default.

Note that if there are pre-existing 0s and 1s, then this method won't work. Also, if the actual vectors are quite long, or if there are a large number of vectors in your list, you should take a look at the `fastmatch` package.

Comment: They want to keep other numbers, like 4,5.

Comment: Ah, thanks, I read the "Incidentally, if any thing else than a symbol comes up (like a letter), than I would like the list to print NA" as return NAs for everything else, but missed that statement in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lapply`:

```
lapply(df, function(x) {
  x <- ifelse(x == "*", 0,  ifelse(x == ".", 1, x))
  gsub("[^*\\.]", NA, x)  
})
```